# ACF block background colour in admin panel

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a bunch of ACF blocks (within an accordion), have added a status field for each block (active or disabled). Basically I want to be able to hide a block on front-end without needing to delete it in admin side, I can do that bit.

Struggling with back-end, if a block status is set to 'disabled', I would like for it be obvious in back-end, so want a different background to other blocks. Below is the code so far. It does not seem understand the if statement, it just adds red bg on all blocks regardless of the status. If I echo out the status, that seems to be assigned to the right block, but if statment doesn't seem to recognise that for some reason.

Just to be clear I need to target blocks which are in the admin panel when editing a page or creating. I have multiple ACF blocks each inside ACF accordion for making it a bit tidy.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
function my_acf_admin_head() { 
    global $post;

    $post_blocks = parse_blocks( get_the_content( '', false, $post->id ) );

    foreach ($post_blocks as $block) {
               
        if ( isset( $block['attrs']['data']['status'] ) ) {
            
            if($block['attrs']['data']['status'] == 'disabled') {
            ?>
                <style>.acf-accordion { background-color: red } </style>
            <?php         
            } else {                            
                ?><style>.acf-accordion { background-color: orange } </style><?php
            }

        }

    }

}

add_action('acf/input/admin_head', 'my_acf_admin_head');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function status_acf_blocks( $block ) {
    $bg_color = false;
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        if ( $block == 'disabled' ) {
            $bg_color = '<style>.acf-block-wrapper { background-color: red; }</style>';
        } else {
            $bg_color = '<style>.acf-block-wrapper { background-color: orange; }</style>';
        }
    }
    return $bg_color;
}
```

Acf block file:

```
...
<?php 
    $status = get_field( 'slug' );
    echo status_acf_blocks( $status );
?>
<div class="acf-block-wrapper">
    
</div>
...
```

Comment: Can you add some details to your answer?

Comment: I showed you other resolve of your problem. status_acf_blocks is globally function to reuse in all blocks.  The logic is very simple, so I don't think I need to write more about the lines.

Comment: @Tapne Perhaps I wasn't too clear I need to target the blocks in the admin panel when creating / editing page/post.